# Export GPX files from QGIS/SAGA that are compatible with Garmin Connect

Tags: qgis, export, saga, gpx, garmin

GPX files exported by QGIS using SAGA do not seem to be accepted by Garmin Connect (web interface). Exporting GPX files via saving a QGIS GPX Layer loses the layers, so I'm using the SAGA export tool.

My workflow is as follows:

- importing a GPX or FIT file to QGIS, via GPX drag & drop or FIT file importer tool
- converting it to a SHP file
- editing points (deleting, adding, correcting, ...)
- "points to line" conversion
- "line smoothing" with SAGA
- "extract vertex" to get points again
- exporting SHP to GPX via SAGA tool `Export gpx`

Garmin Connect doesn't seem to accept such GPX files, but other sites e.g. outdooractive.com are willing to accept them (so I import / export using Outdoor Active to then transfer the files to Garmin Connect).

How can I export GPX files that can be used directly in Garmin Connect? Or are there any alternative methods?

Using QGIS 3.30.

Comment: Are you able to explain why you need to transform the GPX data rather than using it directly? GPX track points generally include time and ele(vation) data with each point. By converting it to a line, and doing other transformations, you will lose the timestamp data, which may be why Garmin Connect is rejecting it. Perhaps you can update the question with a sample of your data after it comes out of QGIS, and after it comes out of Outdoor Active.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your comment. I´m using SHP layer to edit points and to get rid of "artefact points" by line smoothing and than making points again. I realized that even without "points to line", "line smoothing" and "extract vertex" GARMIN CONNECT will not accept exported GPX (from SHP) files - by QGIS or SAGA. Try to dig into data formats, thx!

Comment: There may be better tools for cleaning GPS files than QGIS - I used to use GPS Prune (which has a compress tool). Obviously it depends on exactly how you want to clean the data.

Comment: Ops, found a pretty simple solution:
Editing tracks (not track_points) by adding, deleting vertex points to the track line, and than exporting the SHP-track to GPX (which GARMIN CONNECT accepts).